# Mysql : using mysql_secure_installation on Ubuntu 22 while keeping auth_socket authentication plugin for the root user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-22.04

So, I'm trying to install Mysql on an Ubuntu 22, and after installing the packages and running the server, I'm at the point where it's recommended to use the `mysql_secure_installation` command.

This command automates some security steps. Amongst others, it drops the test database and asks for a password for the root user.

However, the latest Mysql version I'm trying to install (8.0.29), has the "auth_socket" plugin, by default, for root user authentication, and it's a good thing, which I'd like to keep.

But, when I launch `mysql_secure_installation`, I'm asked for a root password, and when I try to give one, I get :

> Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server.

Which is normal because I try to give a password for an authentication method that doesn't require one.

But then, I'm stuck, because `mysql_secure_installation` cannot proceed further.

I know that I can ALTER my root user in the relevant Mysql table, giving it a password and a "mysql_native_password" authentication plugin, but I don't want to do that.

I'd like to keep the "auth_socket" authentication plugin while executing `mysql_secure_installation` until the end.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

---TL;DR:

```bash
# Login to MySQL
mysql
```

```sql
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Insert Very Secret Here';
```

```bash
mysql_secure_installation;
echo "plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so" >> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf;
systemctl restart mysql;
mysql -u root -p
# Use password previously chosen, a.k.a. 'Insert Very Secret Here'
```

```sql
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

---Explanation

Try the following:

1. ALTER your root user to have a password (temporarily);
2. Run `mysql_secure_installation` and complete it successfully;

At this point, you should have a MySQL root account with a password and a server with the required security measures implemented.

3. Edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and add towards its end the line:

```bash
    plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so
```

This will allow the "passwordless" socket authentication.

4. Restart MySQL `systemctl restart mysql`.
5. Login to MySQL, using the root password you previously specified by running `mysql -p` (Provided you're logged in as root, otherwise run `mysql -u root -p`).
6. Execute the following query:

```sql
    ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

You're all set: you have a password-enabled MySQL root account that uses socket authentication as well.